# Writing to a tsv file from multiple list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have two lists

```
ids = [1,2,3]
values = [10,20,30]
```

I need to create a tsv file with two columns - `id` and `result` and put the `ids` and `values` in there. The output should look like this

```
id result
1  10
2  20
3  30
```

I wrote below code

```
output_columns = ['id','result']
data = zip(output_columns, ids, values)
    with open('output.tsv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        tsv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
        tsv_output.writerow(data)
```

But this gives me an output like below which is wrong

```
('id', '1', '10') ('result', '2','20')
```

I understand that this wrong output is because the way I did `zip` to create a row of data. But I am not sure how to solve it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output_columns = ['id','result']
data = zip(ids, values)
    with open('output.tsv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        tsv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
        tsv_output.writerow(output_columns)
        for id, val in data:
            tsv_output.writerow([id, val])
```

Comment: Little typo - `tsv.writerow(output_columns)` should be `tsv_output.writerow(output_columns)`. Otherwise good

Answer (score 2):

It's easier using pandas

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({"ids":[1,2,3], "values":[10,20,30]})

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   ids  values
0    1      10
1    2      20
2    3      30

In [10]: df.to_csv("data.tsv", sep="\t", index=False)
```